# Getting data from JSON array in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

If a website gives json array data as follow

```
mycallback([{"id":"2","name":"Kelly","age":"12"},{"id":"3","name":"Robby","age":"12"}])
```

How i call this `json` array data into a table

My try but didn't worked!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://WebSite_URL.com/data.php",
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "jsonp":"mycallback"

        }
    } );
} );
</script>

<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default DataTables expects the data source to be contained within a variable named `data` like so:

```
{data:[{"id":"2","name":"Kelly","age":"12"},{"id":"3","name":"Robby","age":"12"}]}
```

But, in your case, I am assuming that changing the json format is not an option as it is a Jsonp request. So, I am assuming that your data is formatted as a "flat" array and can't be changed like this:

```
[{"id":"2","name":"Kelly","age":"12"},{"id":"3","name":"Robby","age":"12"}]
```

Now, dataTables allow "flat" array structures to be used by giving the `dataSrc` option within the `ajax` array as a blank value. Also since your data source has a key for each value, you have to specify that using the `columns` option. So, your datatables code would become:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://WebSite_URL.com/data.php",
        "dataType": "jsonp",
        "jsonp":"mycallback",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "id"},
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "age"},
    ]
} );
```

This is of course assuming that your ajax call and jsonp callback are all done properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSONP call and you provide a function name(here "mycallback").So, the server will send data such that it is calling your provided function with the JSON data.Here,mycallback([{"id":"2","name":"Kelly","age":"12{"id":"3","name":"Robby","age":"12"}]).

What you have to do is defining a function with name "mycallback" which will have a parameter and you can do whatever you want there.

Example:

```
  function mycallback(data){
                var table = document.getElementById('example');
                var tableHtml = '' // make the html here with this data (using a template engine)
                table.innerHTML = tableHtml;
          }
```